# How do I make the canvas endless for an infinite runner type of game in JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want the HTML5 canvas to never end so that the square never stops moving, it keeps on "running" so that it can jump over obstacles and the score increases etc. I really do not know how to do this. Please help and thanks in advance. I have posted my code below for everyone to see, I incorporated the JS into the HTML, yep.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Move Square</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="centre">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="100px" width="200px"></canvas>
</div>


<script>

function draw(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
ctx.closePath();


x+=dx/4;

//Draw Square
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,20,20);

clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}

var x = 20;
var y = 20;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 5;




setInterval(draw,10);

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        x+=dx;
    }
    }







</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't think of this problem in terms of making an "infinite" canvas; think of it in terms of repeatedly generating obstacles that come across the screen and are removed from memory when they are no longer visible, creating the illusion of running through a side-scrolling infinite space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make every other object on the canvas move backward if you want your block to run endlessly "forward." Of course, to do this you would need to add another object for reference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Move Square</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="centre">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="100px" width="200px"></canvas>
</div>


<script>

function draw(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
ctx.closePath();




//Draw Square
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,20,20);
//Two extra green squares
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(x2,50,20,20);
ctx.fillRect(x3,50,20,20);
//make them move backwards at the same speed
x2 -= dx/4;
x3 -= dx/4;

}

var x = 20;
var y = 20;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 5;
//X coordinates for green blocks:
var x2 = 50;
var x3 = 250;



setInterval(draw,10);

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
//document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        x+=dx;
    }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```